# How in Java to turn a string[] whose contents are hexidecimal values of individual bytes in to byte[]

Tags: java, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I came upon an issue in React-Native interacting with NativeModules, where in Java passing a String from React-Native to the Java host trimmed the string of null chars. The string in question is "R\u0000" which represents fine in both Java and React-Native. However when typecasting between the two, the null value is erased and only "R" comes through.

You can imagine how funny it is to trim trailing zeros in a number, but it is second nature in strings. These strings represent binary sequences largely for BLE communications, and trimming is destructive.

So it came upon me to interpret each letter of the string as a hexidecimal value in an array of strings. In the JS, a Uint8Array goes from [82,0] (decimal) to [52,0] and then as a string ["52", "0"]. The array ["52", "0"] arrives in Java fine.

I'm weak in Java and struggling here. I need to turn these strings whose contents are hexidecimal values of bytes, in to a byte[].

Comment: This did not happen 'in typecasting'. It happened because someone used a C string function that stops at trailing nulls. And hex is a notation, not a value type. The contents of your byte array are binary.

Comment: user207421 thank you for explaining why this string gets truncated. Abra, I did quite a bit of research and was quite confused with the lack of documentation on React Native and types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String[] input = {"52", "0"};
    int length = input.length;
    byte[] output = new byte[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        output[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(input[i], 16);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
}
```

output:

```
[82, 0]
```

Comment: I will try this; I have some questions though maybe I misunderstand Java. ++i is that the wrong operation should it be i++? Is that not a thing in Java? I.e. the difference between ++i and i++

Comment: There is a difference, but they are equivalent in this particular case.

Comment: This answer worked very well thank you. I did have to make some changes to the algorithm for my specific case in React Native, but what is important is the typecasting in `output[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(input[i], 16);`

In the react-native arena, you need to use ReadableArrays, where you must know the type and the index in advance.  Something like

`for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        output[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(customData.getString(i), 16);
`

Comment: Hey @mokyabe thanks for helping me! I hope my selecting your answer boosts your rep. Apparently this question is not desired by the StackOverflow, so I may just copy the question and answer to reddit so it can actually help people in the future.